# Spring Data/Hibernate - Propagating Generated Keys

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Usually I'm able to Google my way out of asking questions here (thank you SO community), but I'm a bit stuck here. This problem has to do with propagating generated keys to joined objects when calling `JpaRepository.save()`

We have entities that are defined like so:

Parent object

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "appointment")
public class Appointment implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "APPT_ID", columnDefinition = "integer")
    private Long apptId;

    ...

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = ApptReminder.class, mappedBy = "appointment", cascade = {
            CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private List<ApptReminder> apptReminders = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Child Object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "appt_reminder")
public class ApptReminder implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ReminderKey reminderKey = new ReminderKey();

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private Appointment appointment;
}
```

Embedded Id Class

```
@Embeddable
public class ReminderKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "APPT_ID", columnDefinition = "integer")
    private Long apptId;

    @Column(name = "CALL_NUM", columnDefinition = "integer")
    private Short callNum;

    ....
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface AppointmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Appointment, Long> {
}
```

And we have a bunch of sets of objects hanging off of the child object all sharing the embedded key attributes. When we call save on the parent object `appointmentRepository.save(appointment)` the child objects get saved, but the appt_id of the first appointment inserted gets an auto generated key of 1, and the first apptReminder record gets an appt_id of 0.

This affects all joined objects that share the embedded ID of `ReminderKey` with similar and predictable effects.

When we call `appoitnmentRepository.save(appointment)` on the top level entity, how do we get the autogenerated keys to propagate through to child entities? I feel like this should be very easy. Perhaps there's an element of the way I laid out the mappings or the usage of an embedded id that's preventing this from working.

One last thing of note is that this is running against an H2 database while in development, but will be used against MySQL afterwards. This could be attributable to H2's MySQL compatibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this way:

Detach appointment from apptReminder on persist operations:

```
public class Appointment implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "APPT_ID", columnDefinition = "integer")
    private Long apptId;

    ...

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = ApptReminder.class, mappedBy = "appointment", cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private List<ApptReminder> apptReminders = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Create a DAO to handle persistence operations:

```
@Repository
public class AppointmentDAO {

    @Autowired
    private AppointmentRepository appointmentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ApptReminderRepository apptReminderRepository;

    public List<Appointment> save(List<Appointment> appointments) {
        appointments.forEach(a -> this.save(a));
        return appointments;
    }

    public Appointment save(Appointment appointment) {
        final Appointment appt = appointmentRepository.save(appointment);
        List<ApptReminder> apptReminders = appointment.getApptReminders();
        apptReminders.forEach(a -> {
            a.getReminderKey().setApptId(appt.getApptId());
            a.getReminderTags().forEach(t -> t.setApptId(appt.getApptId()));
            a.getReminderMessages()
                    .forEach(m -> m.getReminderMessageKey().setApptId(appt.getApptId()));
            a.getMsgQueueReminder().setApptId(appt.getApptId());
        });
        apptReminderRepository.saveAll(apptReminders);
        return appointment;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `JoinColumns` annotation to marry `Appointment` `apptId` to `ReminderKey` `apptId`.

Comment: It's not a one to one mapping, it's a one to many. The primary key of apptReminder is appt_id, call_num. The call_num is an ordinal, and makes up the second half of the composite key.